# Structure is contained in itself. How to understand this?

Tags: c++, c

I am keen on someone else's code and want to understand what is happening here.
What is stored in this structure?

Is this some kind of pattern in C?

```
typedef struct _P_NEXT P_NEXT;
struct _P_NEXT {P_NEXT *p_el;};
```

Comment: It's not the structure that is in itself, but a pointer to another instance of the same structure. Very commonly used for container structures (linked lists, trees, ...)

Comment: Looks like a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Comment: Aside: please note that a leading _underscore is reserved for system/library use.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller can be a pointer to itself, not necessary to *another* ^^

Comment: thank,didn't even think about it.
Immediately the code is clearer.

Comment: @bruno very true, or it could be NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure contains a pointer, not the structure itself. Pointer is essentially an address in memory. The pointer type (P_NEXT, in this case) just tell what is the interpretation of the memory block should be.

This struct looks like a list: a node which points to the next node in list (I guess there is an extra "data" attribute)

Comment: *Pointer is essentially a number representing address in memory* : just say a pointer is an address, to speak about a *number representing* is not a very good idea for me

Comment: I'll agree and I will change it. I do believe thinking about it as number help in understanding why it's okay to use arithmetic operands on addresses.

Comment: I have given the full structure. There is no data field.

Comment: @АлександрРахмаев it is valid to have that list definition, but its interest is very limited ^^